# rsync copy content from joe@remote:/foo/bar/baz to b without creating b/foo/bar/a

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to copy a remote file from a variable path (here shown as `/foo/bar/baz`) to a local path (here shown as `b`).

```
rsync -a joe@remote:/foo/bar/baz b # created b/foo/bar/baz
                                   # instead of creating b/baz
```

How to get rsync to only create `baz` in the target folder instead of the whole remote path?

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered the question, but the answer seems to have been deleted.

As shown by the rsync man page, `./` can be used to control how much path context is created in the target.

In my case the correct call would have been:

```
rsync -a joe@remote:/foo/bar/./baz b
```